# Can't get into 3rd puzzle

Tags: hacker-experience

I have tried, but I can't get into the server that has the meme on the index in Hacker Experience. I'm really stuck.

IP:
!!Spoiler ALERT!!

> 125.169.195.182

Comment: By 'get in' do you mean you can't hack in or you can't solve he puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

The following question is found within the puzzle:

> What is the name of the volcano who erupted in 2010 and shut down much of Europe's airspace ?

The right answer is
`Eyjafjallajökull`.